# Evenly split Internet traffic cap among multiple people

Tags: networking, internet, bandwidth, multiple-users

Our Internet connection has a data cap. We have been going over it recently.

A friend somehow split the data cap into parts so that everyone gets their own part but cannot use up others’ parts. How would I set that up?

Router: Linksys E2500

So my friend set it up so there were different networks in the house for each person to use. He could track each persons data usage and decide to turn off the internet. He would also turn also turn off and on the internet during the day, so then it wouldn't be used all day.

Comment: why not ask him?

Comment: This will all depend on the available features of your router but implementing a monthly bandwidth cap per device is not a standard option.

Comment: Sorry I rewrote the question, but I found it hard to understand. You should definitely ask your friend. A regular consumer router with stock firmware won’t be able to do that. How exactly are you accessing the Internet? What’s your router’s (if any) make and model?

Answer (score 0):

Some routers, allow you to specify how much bandwidth certain clients can use. Most consumer routers only allow to limit bandwidth speed and not how much data the client can consume.

So there are a couple ways to do this, either you go out and research which routers will allow you to do this. Or you can setup a network server to do this for you, which in my opinion would be easier to do. The server can monitor the traffic and limit your clients based on bandwidth usage.

If you go with the server option, you would need to have a switch to allow multiple connections to your server or you can use your router, with the firewall and DHCP disabled, and have the server take over as the DHCP server, firewall and DNS server and your router can then act as a switch.

The server can be windows, however I am not familiar with windows servers or using windows to monitor traffic. So I can only tell you how to do this with a linux server. The linux distro doesn't matter as long as it supports iptables which most distros do. I recommend Ubuntu server or desktop, either or will work and is more user friendly then most other linux distros.

You would then use something like below in a terminal window.

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.1.10 -m quota --quota 5368709120 -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 192.168.1.10 -m quota --quota 5368709120 -j ACCEPT

what this does, is it sets whoever is using ip 192.168.1.10 to have a quota of 5gb and only accepts packets if its below this quota from udp or tcp protocols.
You will have to do this with every ip address you want to limit.

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j CLASSIFY --set-class 1:12

this sets over-quota packets to a tc class of your choice. TC is another program on linux you can use for limiting various other things with the traffic as well. [TC Man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tc)